# Does visual studio code support autocompletion on dot, parenthesis, and other context-dependent character?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I prefer visualstudio-like autocompletion style to vsc-style.

In Visual Studio 2017, whenever I type certain character (dot, parenthesis, space) Visual Studio autocompletes to what I selected.

Taking intelliJ, It can be controlled in Preference Settings.
You can check "Insert selected suggestions by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys"

But I can't find this in any settings on Visual Studio Code.

It seems that It doesn't support this feature.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Have you had a look at this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true,` in settings.json